# CSS how to vertically center image and text without changing style of image

Tags: css, image, text, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have an image and some text. I want to center both of them vertically in `<div`>.
How can I do this while **NOT** changing anything in the `<img>` tag?

I know lots of people suggest the following:

```
<div>
<img style="vertical-align:middle; height: 30px;" src ="image.png"/>
<span style="line-height: 30px;" > my text </span> 
</div>
```

Because of some reasons, I do not want to change anything in the `<img>` tag. Can I center both of them by only adding styles in `<div>` or `<span>` or other places?

By the way, I also know that some people said the following would work:

```
<div>
<img height=30px; src ="image.png"/>
<span style="line-height: 30px;" > my text </span>
</div>
```

But it is not working for me. So any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you unable to include an external stylesheet into the document?

Comment: What HTML and CSS are you starting with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/J4QJA/

```
div {
    height: 300px;
    background: beige;
    line-height: 300px;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
​
```

...

**UPDATE**

In case you can't/don't want to apply ANY styles to the `<img>` you can use a wrapper - http://jsfiddle.net/J4QJA/3/

*HTML*

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        Lorem ipsum doloe sit amet
    </div>
</div>​
```

*CSS*

```
div.wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    background: beige;
}

div.image-wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; /* half of your image height */
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. but As I said, I cannot add any styles in < img> tag, which means I cannot put "vertical-align: middle;" there for img. I know this will work, but it does not solve what I asked.

Comment: No need to add the `height` and `line-height` to the `<div>`: http://jsfiddle.net/J4QJA/1/

Comment: @user1387727: so you want the `<img>` tag to have different styles, but you don’t want to apply any styles to it?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite that's just in case the `div` will be taller than the image - http://jsfiddle.net/J4QJA/2/

Comment: @user1387727 You **MUST** use inline CSS only?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to apply any styles to < img> tag. The reason is hard to explain. But that is what I am looking for. How can I not apply any styles to image but I can still vertically center both image and text. @PaulD.Waite

Comment: @ZoltanToth I could use anything else, but not apply styles to image. How is it accomplished?

Comment: btw, applying style to image from outside of < img> tag is allowed.

Comment: @user1387727: “btw, applying style to image from outside of `<img>` tag is allowed”. What do you mean? @ZoltanToth’s CSS applies `vertical-align: middle` to the `<img>` tag from “outside” of the `<img>` tag, i.e. from a `<style>` tag or an external stylesheet. Do you mean something else by “from outside of `<img>` tag”?

Comment: I mean it is allowed from its parent <tag> 
for example, <div  ***add style here to affect image*** > <imge /> text </div>

Comment: @ZoltanToth what do you mean, could you give me some example?

Comment: @user1387727: ZoltanToth did give you an example: click on the link in his comment.

Comment: oh my god! this is the ANSWER I am looking for. The solution is a little bit complicated for me though. but in my restricted conditions, you solved it. Thank you @ZoltanToth